# Conda environment variable referencing another variable

Tags: environment-variables, conda

In a conda environment file, the `variables` key can be used set particular environment variables in the created environment. However, I cannot figure out how to make the value be dependent on another environment variable. This is particularly useful if a variable needs to contain a path relative to `CONDA_PREFIX`.

```yaml
channels:
- conda-forge
variables:
  TZDIR: ${CONDA_PREFIX}/share/zoneinfo
dependencies:
- tzdata
```

In an environment created using the above environment file, the `TZDIR` variable is just literally `${CONDA_PREFIX}/share/zoneinfo`—the `CONDA_PREFIX` variable was not resolved.